# Containable behavior doesn't return deeper model association and selecting fields

Tags: cakephp

I want to limit the fields returned by a deeper association using containable.

My associations:

Game hasMany Review

The paginate and containable code:

```
$this->paginate = array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'fields' => array(
                'Game.id', 'Game.name',
                'Publisher.id', 'Publisher.name'
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Game' => array(                     
                    'Review' => array(
                        'fields' => array('Review.id', 'ROUND(AVG(Review.score),1)')
                    )
                ),
            )
        );
$games = $this->paginate('Game');
```

Currently, all of the fields in the `Review` table are returned. `'ROUND(AVG(Review.score),1)'` is never returned. How can I specify what fields I want returned from the `Review` association?

---

**SQL dumps** for two search results using @theJetzah's answer. The first is a search with one game as a result and the second is a search returning three games.

```
SELECT `Review`.`id`, `Review`.`review_text`, `Review`.`score`, `Review`.`user_id`, `Review`.`game_id`, `Review`.`created`, `Review`.`platform_id`, (ROUND(AVG(`Review`.`score`),1)) AS `Review__average_score` FROM `videogamedb`.`reviews` AS `Review` WHERE `Review`.`game_id` = (55)

SELECT `Review`.`id`, `Review`.`review_text`, `Review`.`score`, `Review`.`user_id`, `Review`.`game_id`, `Review`.`created`, `Review`.`platform_id`, (ROUND(AVG(`Review`.`score`),1)) AS `Review__average_score` FROM `videogamedb`.`reviews` AS `Review` WHERE `Review`.`game_id` IN (55, 56, 57)
```

Comment: Since you're pagination the `Game` model, why are you including 'Game' inside the 'contain'? Game will be the main table/model?

Comment: @theJeztah: I'm currently in another controller called SearchesController. It's used to handle user searches across the site.

Comment: The *Controller* doesn't define what model you're using, if you specify multiple models in the $uses array, you can use another model as well, e.g. `public $uses = array('ModelA', ModelB');`

Comment: Just realised, that your calculated field will probably not work; since you're using an *aggregate*, the reviews will need to be 'grouped'. Can you explain how the models are related? Is it `Game->hasMany->Review` or `Game->belongsTo->Review`?

Comment: @thaJeztah It is `Game->hasMany->Review`. Also, I do have `public $uses = array('Game');` in my controller.

Comment: @user1927371, although I think @thaJeztah is on to something here, it might be useful to print the generated SQL `$this->element('sql_dump')` to see how far off you actually are.

Comment: @SamDelaney good suggestion, locating problems like this without access to the actual content is always difficult, SQL may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a full answer, but an attempt to get it working :)

### Approach1 (UPDATE: Containable doesn't support 'group by')

First of all, try to add the 'Game' model to the `$uses` array of your Controller, if it is not included yet, and re-organise the pagination array (as previously suggested by Sam), so that you'll be pagination the Game model itself.

Then, It may help to create a virtual field for the calculated score, but the results of 'Review' need to be grouped, otherwise you'll not be able to calculate the *average* score.

I'm not able to test this, but it  may worth trying

something like this;

```
public $uses = array(
    'Game',
    // other models
);

public function myfunction()
{
    $this->Game->Review->virtualFields['average_score'] = 'ROUND(AVG(Review.score),1)';

    $this->paginate = array(
        'Game' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Game.id',
                'Game.name',
                'Publisher.id',
                'Publisher.name'
            ),
            'contain' => array(
                'Review' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'Review.game_id,
                        'Review.average_score',
                    ),
                    'group' => array(
                        'Review.game_id,
                    ),
                )
            )
        )
    );

    // Conditions can be passed to paginate,
    // that way you can specify 'paginate' at
    // one place and don't have to modify it
    // to include the conditions
    $games = $this->paginate('Game', $conditions);
}
```

### Alternative approach: Using joins and a database-view

Apparently, the Containable behavior doesn't like group-by clauses; See this ticket for more information: [Containable behavior does not implement 'group' option](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/579-containable-behavior-does-not-implement-group-option)

CakePHP allows you to manually specify a join: [Joining Tables](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)

To simplify things and to prevent having to add a 'group by' for *all* fields, create a simple database-view in your database;

```
CREATE VIEW review_scores AS
   SELECT 
       game_id, 
       ROUND(AVG(score),1) AS average_score,
       COUNT(id) AS total_reviews
   FROM
       reviews
   GROUP BY
      game_id;
```

If you're unfamiliar with this; a database 'view' is basically a 'stored query', which can be accessed as if it was a regular table. See [Create View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html)

Then, use a 'manual' join, using the newly created database-view as the source-table. In your case, this will look something like this;

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Game' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Game.id',
            'Game.name',
            'Publisher.id',
            'Publisher.name',
            'ReviewScore.average_score',
            'ReviewScore.total_reviews',
        ),
        'joins' => array(
            array(
                'table' => 'review_scores',
                'alias' => 'ReviewScore',
                'type'  => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                    'ReviewScores.game_id = Game.id',
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @thaJetzah: Using your code, when my search returns only one game as a result, I get the correct average score for that game. However, when a search returns more than one game, only one average score is returned and it is the average score of all the reviews for all of the games returned. I've added the **sql dumps** as an edit to my question.

Comment: @user1927371 The problem is that the Containable behavior seems to ignore the `fields` and the `group`. I'm not really sure if the behavior is *supposed* to support this. Do you only need the **average** score per game? A good solution for this would be to create a view in your database and use that as the source for a model. I'll add an example.

Comment: @thaJetzah: Thanks for the help. Your alternate solution worked. I didn't know about database views and they seem very useful. Thanks.

Comment: @user1927371 database views are indeed very useful; they can be a welcome 'abstraction' layer to simplify using complicated queries. Personally, I prefix my views with `vw_` to easier distinguish if it's a view or an actual database-table. Anyway glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your array is a configured a little wrong, try:

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'Game' => array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'fields' => array(
            'Game.id', 'Game.name',
            'Publisher.id', 'Publisher.name'
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Review' => array(
                'fields' => array('Review.id', 'ROUND(AVG(Review.score),1)')
            )
        )
    )
);
$games = $this->paginate('Game');
```

As an aside, from personal experience, specifying the fields in a query doesn't always speed it up (certainly for small number of fields), assuming this is the motive for doing so. It does reduce memory occupancy but this is only relative to original size of the record and the number of records returned.

Comment: I re-arranged my array and it returns the exact same results.